# Writes to database seem to have no effect

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, web-config, iis-6, httpmodule

I am working with an ASP.NET web application written in C# deployed to IIS/Windows Server 2008 R2. The application uses NHibernate to interact with an Oracle database running on a networked unix server.

It seems that writes being made by the application to the database have no effect.

If I manually edit the value of a record in the Oracle database, the new value is reflected by the application. However, if I attempt to change a value using the application’s custom “save” functionality, the changes are not reflected in the database. It seems like reads are succeeding, but writes are failing.

Why do writes seem to be failing?

More information:

No obvious error messages are received (ie. the application does not throw an exception and it seems to continue running as if everything is fine).

Another instance of this application is running on IIS/Windows Server 2003. This instance can write to the Oracle database (ie. the changes can immediately be seen in the database by using a database viewer after clicking “save”).

The code is virtually identical between the 2003/2008 applications. However, on the 2008 server, I am using newer versions of Oracle libraries and I changed to target architecture of the visual studio projects from ‘Any CPU’ to ‘x86’ (the 2008 server is 64-bit while the 2003 server is 32-bit).

Disclaimer:

I have very limited experience working with IIS, NHibernate, Oracle databases, Windows Server 2003, and Windows Server 2008 R2. I do, however, have slightly more experience working with C#, ASP.NET web applications, Visual Studio, and MSSQL databases).

Comment: Who knows.  Please show some code of the persistence action.

Comment: As a pure divination, sounds like you are not committing a transaction.

Comment: With all due respect, the application running on the 2003 server uses the exact same persistence code as that running on the 2008 server, and the writes are definitely working on the 2003 server, so I do not believe it is a problem with the code (unless it needs to be written differently because of the different environment, but that seems unlikely to me). Please correct me if I am wrong about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it.

It turns out one of the HttpModules was not being initialized. This was because the web.config file was tuned to IIS6, and the application was running in an application pool set to Integrated Pipeline mode on IIS7. Switching the application pool to Classic mode essentially enabled backwards compatibility.

Anyways, here is the resource that helped me figure it out: [httpModules not working on iis7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2935383/httpmodules-not-working-on-iis7)